# Using mySQL IN() Function containing SELECT

Tags: mysql, case

Is there a way I can do something like this (or how would I do this)?:

```
    SELECT   
    CASE
        WHEN '5150' IN (SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM my_table) THEN
          'result one'
        WHEN '5150' IN (SELECT field4, field5, field6 FROM my_table) THEN
         'result two'
        WHEN '5150' IN (SELECT field7, field8, field9 FROM my_table) THEN
         'result three'
        ELSE 
         'result two'
    END AS my_result;
```

When I run this I get:
    Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Are you trying to match the value `5150` in any of the 3 columns `field1, field2, field3`? Can you post a little more info about your tables - the structure of these two tables via `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a small sample of their rows together with the output you want from the query?

Comment: '5150' would be a value I'm checking against multiple fields, where '5150' would be in any one of them, but in sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT IF('5150' IN (field1, field2, field3), 'result one', 'result two') AS my_result
FROM my_table
```

Note: When you use a subquery, you can only return a *single* field.

UPDATE: Since you seem to want to use the `CASE` statement, try this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN '5150' IN (field1, field2, field3) THEN 'result one'
    WHEN '5150' IN (field4, field5, field6) THEN 'result two'
    WHEN '5150' IN (field7, field8, field9) THEN 'result three'
    ELSE 'result two'
END AS my_result
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry, I should have clarified in my original post (which I have now edited) that I really am wanting to have a range of case's.

Comment: @user3565107: I added to my answer.  The solution is to not use a subquery, and to just have the whole query be `FROM my_table`.